# Неверный подсчёт скалярного произведения строки на столб

Tags: c, математика, динамические-массивы, матрицы

Дана вещественная матрица размером N, все элементы которой различны. Найти скалярное произведение строки, в которой находится наибольший элемент матрицы, на столбец с наименьшим элементом.
При вводе элементов 1-2-3-4,произведение высчитывается правильно,а при 2-3-4-5 - нет. В чём моя ошибка?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, size, jmin=0, imax=0, multip=0, **Massiv;
    printf("\n Vvedite razmer massiva: ");
    scanf_s("\n %d", &size);
    Massiv = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Massiv[i] = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            printf("\n Massiv[%d][%d]= : ",i,j);
            scanf_s("%d ", &Massiv[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int min = Massiv[0][0], max = Massiv[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (Massiv[i][j] < min)
            {
                min = Massiv[i][j];
                jmin = j;
            }
            if (Massiv[i][j] > max)
            {
                max = Massiv[i][j];
                imax = i;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            multip += Massiv[imax][j] * Massiv[i][jmin];
        }
    }

    printf("\n Rezultat ymnojeniya = %d", multip);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        free(Massiv[i]);
    }
    free(Massiv);
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В отладчике смотрели?

Comment: Для начала - вот тут `Massiv[i] = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));` нужен просто `sizeof(int)`...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Смотрю - у вас ответ универсальный :) Но он не очень-то пригоден при неверном понимании алгоритма. Ну будет человек убеждаться, что произведения и суммы вычисляются верно, а дальше?...

Comment: @Harry Спасибо за совет,но проблема осталась.При символах 1-2-3-4 произведение равняется 8.Видимо,я в каком-то ещё  месте ошибся.

Comment: См. обновленный ответ. Вы же еще и вводите не то, что хотите...

Comment: @Harry Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что вы тут считаете?

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        multip += Massiv[imax][j] * Massiv[i][jmin];
    }
}
```

Как правильно рассчитывается скалярное произведение, а?

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    multip += Massiv[imax][i] * Massiv[i][jmin];
}
```

Еще выкиньте нафиг из `scanf` всякие `\n` и прочие пробелы.

http://rextester.com/UBVUGE15058 - вот рабочий пример.